# How can I separate stereo microphone input channels by Web Audio API javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

I try to separate stereo microphone channels with following javascript and Web Audio API.. but it is not working as I expected.
The input stereo microphone is designed to separate telephone conversation in ch0(speaking) and ch1(receiving). This stereo microphone is working fine with QuickTime audio recording. speaking and receiving voice are separated to L and R. With Firefox, The speaking and receiving voice are mixed on splitter's channel0. and nothing on channel1. with Chrome, The speaking and receiving voice are mixed and appears on both channel0 and channel1 of splitter. My goal is to separate the speaking voice on channel0 and receiving voice on channel1.
the function is callbacked when Microphone permission granted in navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}.

Does anyone have advise?

```js
Microphone.prototype.onMediaStream = function(stream) {
  var audioTrack=stream.getAudioTracks();
  var audioStreamTrackName = audioTrack[0].label;
  var audioStreamTrackType = audioTrack[0].kind;
  console.log('onMediaStream: getAudioTracks:[0] '+ audioStreamTrackName +' '+ audioStreamTrackType);
  var AudioCtx = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var maxdb =-10.0, mindb=-80.0, fft=2048, smoothing =0.8,maxVol=1.0,minVol=0.0;
  if (!AudioCtx)
    throw new Error('AudioContext not available');
  if (!this.audioContext)
   this.audioContext = new AudioCtx();
// create two analyser
   this.analyser0 = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
   this.analyser0.fftSize = fft;
   this.analyser0.minDecibels=mindb;
   this.analyser0.maxDecibels=maxdb;
   this.analyser0.smoothingTimeConstant=smoothing;
   this.analyser1 = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
   this.analyser1.fftSize = fft;
   this.analyser1.minDecibels=mindb;
   this.analyser1.maxDecibels=maxdb;
   this.analyser1.smoothingTimeConstant=smoothing;
   this.splitter = this.audioContext.createChannelSplitter(2);   //2ch splitter Stereo to 2 monoral stream
   this.merger = this.audioContext.createChannelMerger(2);       //2ch marger   two monoral to stereo
   this.gainCh0 = this.audioContext.createGain();
   this.gainCh1 = this.audioContext.createGain();
   this.gainCh0.gain.value = maxVol;    // max 
   this.gainCh1.gain.value = maxVol;    // max
   if (!this.mic) {
    this.mic = this.audioContext.createScriptProcessor(8192,2,2);
   }
   this.mic.onaudioprocess = this._onaudioprocess.bind(this);
   this.stream = stream;
   this.audioInput = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
// audio-nodes connections   
   this.audioInput.connect(this.splitter);
   this.splitter.connect(this.gainCh0, 0);     // connect splitter output channel0 to gainCh0
   this.splitter.connect(this.gainCh1, 1);     // connect splitter output channel1 to gainCh
   this.gainCh0.connect(this.merger, 0, 0);    //connect gainCh0 output channel0 to merger input channel0 
   this.gainCh1.connect(this.merger, 0, 1);    //connect gainCh1 output channel0 to merger input channel1 
   this.merger.connect(this.mic);              // connect merger to ScriptProcessor
   this.mic.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
   this.gainCh0.connect(this.analyser0);
   this.gainCh1.connect(this.analyser1);
// start recording
   this.onStartRecording();
};
```

[firefox web audio debug tool output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D4hR.png)

Comment: If graph at image is expected pattern should `this.mic.connect(this.audioContext.destination);` be last `.connect()` call?

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I moved this.mic.connect(th‌​is.audioContext.desti‌​nation); to just after this.gainCh1connect(this.analyser1); but the situation has not changed.

Comment: Try to set the `echoCancelation` constraint to `false`, it may be `googEchoCancelation` in chrome. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387737#c4

Comment: Kaiido, Thank you for your advise,  I changed my getUserMedia with following constraint combination, then now it works as I expected on chrome. it may not work if I set true to any of 4 options. and echoCancelation still works. Thank you.
    "mandatory": {
      "echoCancellation": false, 
      "googAutoGainControl": false,
      "googNoiseSuppression": false,
      "googHighpassFilter": false
      },
    "optional": []
    }},
    this.onMediaStream.bind(this), 
    this.onPermissionRejected.bind(this)); 
};

Comment: `"googEchoCancellation": false`  required for windows chrome.